# Burger Icon Not Completely Clickable

Tags: html, css, hamburger-menu

everyone,

I've created a burger icon using box-shadow for the first time, but for some reason, only the top bar is a hyperlink: http://jsfiddle.net/vq5r0r8j.

Markup: `<a href="#menu" class="box-shadow-menu"></a>`

CSS:

```
.box-shadow-menu {
    position: relative;
}

.box-shadow-menu:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 4px;
        background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 0 0 white, 0 20px 0 0 white;
}
```

Any help resolving this issue would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set your `a` to `display:block` because `a` by default is set `inline` and you have to give it `height` as well (same as the parent)

snippet:

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.body {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #4dc1df;
}
.navicon {
    text-align: center;
}
.box-shadow-menu {
    position: relative;
    display:block; /* NEW */
    height:45px; /* NEW */
}
.box-shadow-menu:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 4px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 0 0 white, 0 20px 0 0 white;
}
.header-text {
    width: 950px;
    font-family:;
    font-size: 38px;
    line-height: 46px;
    color: #c44628;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="navicon">
      <a href="#menu" class="box-shadow-menu"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="header-text"></div>
  </div>
```